# how many integers are in a 16 kb array

Tags: arrays, memory, size, cuda

i am asking this question because i am programming on gpus with cuda. the shared memory is 16kb , therefore i need to know what is the maximum sized integer array i can create?
is it also possible to create a large array about (3,000,000 integers) if i have a 4GB memory? what is the right way to calculate this? is an integer which is 4 bytes on a 32 bit OS, is 8B on a 64 bit system? thefore the same array of integers on a 64 bit OS will have the double memory space than on 32 bit OS? i feel lost when it comes to memory space calculation... can anybody "tutorial" me?

i am using c as a programming language...

Comment: What programming language are you using? 'integer' means different things (and different sizes) in different languages.

Comment: That would depend on the size of the largest integer you need to store?

Comment: it depends on the integer? so a 5 will take less space than 100?

Comment: No, but a int32 takes less space than a int64

Answer (score 1):

Whether integers are 32 or 64 bits (or something else) depends on your processor, OS, and compiler settings, as well as the exact data type you are using.  I believe `int` is 32 bits on common platforms, and `long long` is 64.  What `long` is varies: on x86 Linux, it's 32 bits on a 32-bit machine and 64 bits on a 64-bit machine.  I think Windows does something different, though.  In terms of computing sizes, you can determine how many bytes an array of `T` will take by `size * sizeof(T)`; by hand, you can multiply the size by the number of bits in the number divided by 8.  So, a 16kB memory can store 4k 32-bit integers or 2k 64-bit ones, and a 3M element array will take 12MB for 32-bit integers and 24MB for 64-bit.  You can choose the data size independently of your hardware.  You might also want to look at C99's `<stdint.h>` to get integer types with particular bit sizes.

Comment: so i should always use a 32 bit OS if i need more memory?

Comment: You can use 32-bit integer types on a 64-bit OS.  In particular, `int` is 32 bits by default on 64-bit x86 systems, even with a 64-bit operating system.  A 64-bit OS can allow you to access more memory (above the 2GiB or 3GiB limit for a 32-bit application) if your system has that much.